# Whether an extension is separable or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

It is a well known conclusion that if $K/F$ is a finite separable extension, then $K^{Emb(K/F)}=F$ (By which I mean the subfield of K fixed by $Emb(K/F)$). I am wondering, whether the inverse is true.

My current idea is that we can show $K^{Emb(K/F)}=F$ is equivalent to $\forall u \in K-F$, $MinPoly_F(u)$ has at least 2 distinct roots. But can it imply that $K/F$ is separable?

(I also posted in MO.)

Comment: I've only seen the notation $K^H$ for $H$ an automorphism group, what does it mean here? But you may want to check out this pdf which may or may not be helpful (since I'm not sure about your notation I can't check myself) http://www.ryancreich.info/galois_theory.pdf

Comment: Yes it is true.

Comment: Please give a link to the MO post, and give a link at the MO post to this post.

Comment: The link to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206185/whether-an-extension-is-separable-or-not?noredirect=1#comment511297_206185

Comment: @user220124 Again, requesting clarification about the notation as the commenter on the MO post did.